# How to replace/uninstall angular dart Module at runtime?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Lets say I have angular dart module as below

```
class CarouselModule extends Module {
  CarouselModule() {
    install(new TransitionModule());
    bind(Carousel);
    bind(Slide);
  }
}

Application app = applicationFactory()
    ..addModule(new CarouselModule());

app.run();
```

Now at runtime, I want switch to a different module. Is this possible in angular-dart?